# Projection operators in non-equiibrium statistical mechanics - non-euclidean function space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, non-equilibrium

In the formalism proposed by Zwanzig and Mori [1,2] for projection operators, an inner product is defined for the variables of phase space which is given by,

$$
(A,B) = \int d\Gamma f_{eq}(\Gamma)A(\Gamma)B(\Gamma) \tag{1}
$$

where $f_{eq}(\Gamma)$ is the equilibrium distribution function. For example in the case of NVT ensemble, for an inverse temperature $\beta$, it is given by,

$$
f_{eq}(\Gamma) = \frac{ e^{-\beta H(\Gamma)}}{\int d\Gamma e^{-\beta H(\Gamma)}}
$$

My question is the following, 
Can the inner product defined in eq.(1) be considered as an inner product in some non-Euclidean function space, where $f_{eq}(\Gamma)$ is the associated metric of the space? Is this mathematically consistent?